# Why scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc is not converging to the optimum solution in my code?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm trying to implement Coursera's Machine learning course in Python. I want tu use scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc to find the optimum theta values to minimize the logregcost function below.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as op

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

def logregcost(theta,X,y):
    m=len(y)
    h_theta=sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta))
    J_theta=((1/m)*sum(-y*np.log(h_theta)-(1-y)*np.log(1-h_theta)))[0]
    return J_theta

def logreggrad(theta,X,y):
    m=len(y)
    h_theta=sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta[:,np.newaxis]))
    grad_theta=(((1/m)*np.dot(X.T,h_theta-y)).T)[0,:]
    return grad_theta

#Initialize theta
initial_theta=np.zeros([n,1])
initial_cost = logregcost(initial_theta, X_train, y_train)
print('Initial cost :',initial_cost)

#Try with a "manual" theta
test_theta=np.array([[-24],[0.2],[0.2]])
test_cost= logregcost(test_theta, X_train, y_train)
print('test cost :',test_cost)

#Train logistic regression
result=op.fmin_tnc(func=logregcost,x0=initial_theta.flatten(),fprime=logreggrad,args=(X_train,y_train))
theta_opt=result[0]
cost_opt= logregcost(theta_opt,X_train,y_train)
print('opt cost :',cost_opt,'opt theta :',theta_opt)
```

The code is running without error but is not finding the optimum. I get a better result with the test_theta manually implemented than the theta found by fmin_tnc (see the result below)

> Initial cost : 0.693147180559946

> test cost : 0.218330193826598

> opt cost : 0.676346827187955 opt theta : [4.42735721e-05 5.31690927e-03 4.98646266e-03]

I already verified that the logregcost and logreggrad functions give the expected results for some values of theta.

Thanks for your help.